# Conditional string extension in r

Tags: r

I would like to extend certain strings in a dataframe column if they match a regex

Input:

```
FD_Object<-list(x="a stricture",x="an ulcer",x="inflammation",x="a nodule",x="a polyp")
FD_Location<-list(x="oesophagus at (cm)",x="GOJ",x="fundus",x="stomach body",x="stomach antrum",x="duodenal bulb",x="D1/D2 angle",x="second part of the duodenum",x="third part of the duodenum")
FD_LesionGen<-list(x="Flat",x="friable",x="nodular",x="malignant-looking")

FD1<-replicate(1000,paste("There is",sample(FD_Object,1,replace=F),"in the",sample(FD_Location,1,replace=F),".It is",sample(3:10,1),"mm in length and ",sample(FD_LesionGen,1,replace=F)))

FD1<-data.frame(FD1)
```

My attempt so far:

```
   if (str_detect(FD1[,1],"polyp")){
  paste("Hi",FD1[1,])
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in if (str_match(FD1[, 1], "polyp")) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (str_match(FD1[, 1], "polyp")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I make the match logical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're giving `grepl` or `str_detect` a vector of strings to check so your output is a vector of logicals. You could use `apply` to apply your conditional function to each element individually:

```
out <- apply(FD1, 1, function(x) {
    if (stringr::str_detect(x, "polyp")) {
        return(paste("Hi", x))
    } else {
        return(x)
    }
})
```

Comment: @divisiban. Aha. I had a feeling that might be the case. Thanks works perfectly

Comment: This is a very awkward solution: bypassing the vectorized functionality of `grepl` or `str_detect`, only to add it back again using apply. There is no need for an if statement.

Comment: @Jordi: You make a good point. I think this answer most clearly explains why Sebastian was having that error, but your answer is undeniably more elegant (hence why I upvoted it)

Comment: @divibisan In that light, it may have some value to Sebastian. I just feel that it should come with a warning that it is an unnecessary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grepl`:

```
a <- letters[1:3]
bool <- grepl("b", a)
a[bool] <- paste("pre", a[bool])
```

Comment: I get the same error as Aaron Gordon and nothing is appended

Comment: Try changing the column to character: `FD[[1]] <- as.character(FD[[1]])`

Comment: Also, I think you are trying to put this into an if statement which will lead to that error since the if statement expects a single logical. Use the logical vector to index and forget about the if statement in this case. (See my example).

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

FD1 %>% 
  mutate(FD1 = ifelse(str_detect(FD1, "polyp"), paste("Hi", FD1), as.character(FD1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try `str_detect()` instead of `str_match()`.

Comment: I get the error: Warning message:
In if (str_detect(FD1[, 1], "polyp")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.  Also nothing is appended...